Flutter jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk Not working on APK release
i am working on jitsi_meet_flutter_sdk And working fine on debug mode but when trying to test on release apk it crashes on join what to do any help
i added file in android/app proguard-rules.pro.rtf
and in build.gradle files made some code
buildTypes {
    release {
        // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
        // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
        signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

here is my main code when app is crashing on release
void join() async{
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   var options = JitsiMeetConferenceOptions(
    serverURL: "https://meet.ffmuc.net/",
    room: "ABXYZ00",
    configOverrides: {
      "startWithAudioMuted": false,
      "startWithVideoMuted": false,
      "subject" : "Jitsi with Flutter",
    },
    featureFlags: {
      "unsaferoomwarning.enabled": false
    },
    userInfo: JitsiMeetUserInfo(
        displayName: "Flutter user",
        email: "user@example.com"
    ),
  );
   try{
     jitsiMeet.join(options);
   }
   catch (error, stackTrace) {
     await prefs.setString('action', error.toString());
     print("Error joining Jitsi meeting: $error");
     print("Stack trace: $stackTrace");
   }
}


Have you followed the instructions displayed on pub.dev page ? And show a dialog with the error and add here. You can remove the dialog once the error got fixed !

yes i did but nothing works me @NaveenAvidi Avidi
